# Upek fingerprint reader not detected by lsusb (X230, Xubuntu 20.04)

Tags: thinkpad, xubuntu, fingerprint

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Lenovo Thinkpad X230, which features an integrated Upek fingerprint reader. From other posts, I've seen that the `fprintd` added support for this device circa 2013, but I have the deeper problem of the system not even detecting the device.

`lsusb` should list a `147e:20xx` device, which conforms to a Upek Biometrics fingerprint reader, but it's simply absent. Only root hubs, Intel Rate Matching Hubs and the on-board webcam are listed.

As far as I know, the BIOS doesn't have control over disabling the device, only enabling it as a "pre-desktop authenticator". I've tried enabling and disabling this setting, to no avail.

Any ideas, is there a H/W fault?

Comment: Check `Security -> I/O Port Access -> Fingerprint` in BIOS if it's disabled and 
you could try `Security -> Reset Fingerprint Data`. The latter will fail if the FPR is not working.

Comment: @Freddy Fantastic - the I/O Port Access setting did it. Not exactly an intuitive place to put the option!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that there *are* options to allow/disallow I/O access of peripherals to the OS. These are located in `Security -> I/O Port Access`. Simply enable the `Fingerprint` option here (and, for some reason `Bluetooth` was also disabled for me, don't know if that's normal). The device will then present itself to the OS.

Thanks to @Freddy in the comments of the question.